# add images to bubble layout in D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

Unable to add images to bubble layout in D3.js . I am trying to append images to the circles in bubble layout but it doesnt works out . the image is not getting transformed.
I want to have look and feel of this:- 
 http://www.cloudshapes.co.uk/labs/attention-hungry-cabinet-ministers/

here is the fiddle link for what I have been trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ankitb/eYGCY/4/

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
              .charge(-300)
              .size([w, h])
              .nodes(nodes)
              .on("tick", tick)
              .start();

    function tick() {
        svg.selectAll("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
    }

    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var d = {
            x: w / 4 + 2 *( Math.random() - 1),
            y: h / 4 + 2 *( Math.random() - 1)
        };
        var personDot = svg.append("g")
                           .attr("class", "g-person-dots")
                           .selectAll("g")
                           .data([d])
                           .enter().append("g")
                           .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x+ "," + d.y + ")"; });
        personDot.append("circle")
                  .data([d]).attr("r", 40)
                  //.attr("r", 1e-6)
        .attr("cx",0).attr("cy",0)
            .transition().style("stroke", "gray").style("fill","white")
              .ease(Math.sqrt);

        personDot.append("image").data([d])
             .attr("xlink:href", "PeopleProfilePicture.jpg")
         //     .attr("x", function (d, i) { return -mugDiameter / 2 - mugDiameter * (i % 9); })
         //.attr("y", function (d, i) { return -mugDiameter / 2 - mugDiameter * (i / 9 | 0); })
             .attr("width", 80)
             .attr("height", 80)
             .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + -d.x / 10 + "," + -d.y / 10 + ")"; });


        if (nodes.push(d) > 10) clearInterval(interval);
        else { force.start(); }

    }, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

The translation of an element is relative to its parent element. That is, by default the element will be in the same position as its parent. Therefore, the translation you need to do does not depend on the dynamic data that you pass in, but only on the dimensions of the image. You need to set `transform` as follows.

```
.attr("transform", "translate(-40,-40)");
```

You may also want to make the background of your images transparent such that you can still see the circle.